# Determinant of a sum of two Hankel matrices

Tags: matrices, determinants

First version: Let $A$ and $B$ be (complex) Hankel matrix. Is it true that $\det (A+B)\neq 0$ if $\det A=0$ and $\det B\neq0$? **No**.

Reformulating: For which $B$ is it true that $\det (A+B)\neq 0$ if $\det A=0$?

Comment: No this is not true. you can easily construct a $3 \times 3$ counterexample: A+B= {zeros on the skew-diagonal, and ones everywhere else}. A= {the upper left corner is 1 and everything else is zero}

Comment: Maybe post the 2nd version of the question as a new question and include something about motivation?

Comment: I think what the 2nd version is asking is, the given condition seems to involve quantifying over all $A$; is it actually a simpler property?

Comment: Yes, it has to be something universal, for all $A$... Actually, it is a problem to make singular matrix non-singular but for the class of Hankel matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, let
$$
B=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 1\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$